# how to find a filtered array in lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

i am working on lodash in which i need to filtered the data from big collection of array.The collection of array is this type of data:

```
[ { poll_options: [ [Object] ],
    responder_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347', '59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b' ],
    voted_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    _id: 5a7878833a1bf4238ddc5cef },
  { poll_options: [ [Object] ],
    responder_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    voted_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    _id: 5a787756217db51698ea8fd6 } ]
```

I want to filter array of which contain the value of ids which is not in voted_ids(i.e for first object it  should return this `59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b` nd for second collections it should return empty array) that means i have to return only those values which are not on voted_ids but in responder_ids. my code  is this

```
_.map(polls,(poll) => {
                        // console.log(poll.responder_ids)
                        return _.filter(poll.responder_ids,(responder) => {
                          return _.find(poll.voted_ids,(voted) => {
                            return !_.includes(responder,voted)
                          })
```

but it does not returning filtered array istead it return whole collections.Where I am doing wrong??

Now its returning result like this...

```
[ [ '59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b' ], [] ]
```

I want single array not multiarray.

Comment: `_.filter` always returns a truthy value, you probably want `_.some` instead.

Comment: instead `_.map` use `_.flatMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `_.filter` in a wrong way.

Filter iterates over all items in your array. If the filter function returns `true` the item will be returned in the filtered array and if it returns `false` it will not be returned.

You however are returning an array, which results to `truthy` and therefore all items are returned.

What you want is something like:

```js
const polls = [
  { 
    poll_options: [ '[Object]' ],
    responder_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347', '59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b' ],
    voted_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    _id: '5a7878833a1bf4238ddc5cef'
  },
  { 
    poll_options: [ '[Object]' ],
    responder_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    voted_ids: [ '5a7189c14615db31ecd54347' ],
    _id: '5a787756217db51698ea8fd6'
  }
];

let ids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < polls.length; i++) {
  ids = [...ids, ...polls[i].responder_ids.filter(id => {
    return !polls[i].voted_ids.includes(id);
  })];
}
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: what should i use instead of filter??

Comment: Thanks got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to use `filter` function. In the callback function you should return some `boolean` value so the array could be filtered by that criteria.
If I understand you correctly you want to filter through array to get array which will contain all results when the id is in the `responder_ids` but no in the `voted_ids`. It could be resolved in various ways, i.e.:

```
_.filter(polls, poll => _.findIndex(poll.responder_ids, id => id === '59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b') > -1 && _.findIndex(poll.voted_ids, id => id === '59ffb41f62d346204e0a199b') === -1;
    );
```